# How to get the format I am looking for

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-query

I am have trouble formatting my data the way I would like So I can make the proper chart.

Current data supplied:

```
2020-01-28 | (direct)           | 13
2020-01-28 | search.google.com  | 3
2020-01-29 | facebook.com       | 1
2020-01-29 | google             | 1 
2020-01-30 | google             | 2
2020-01-30 | search.google.com  | 2
2020-02-02 | google             | 1
```

I trying to get the following output

```
           | (direct) | search.google.com | google | facebook.com
2020-01-28 | 13       | 3                 | 0      | 0
2020-01-29 | 0        | 0                 | 1      | 1
2020-01-30 | 0        | 2                 | 2      | 0
2020-02-02 | 0        | 0                 | 1      | 0
```

On another post I found the following query which is not quite what I am looking for:

```
=QUERY('DataSource'!A1:C7,"select A, sum(C), count(C) group by A,B",-1)
```

Answer (score 1):

Never mind, I found the answer I was looking for. but here it is for anyone looking:

```
=QUERY('datasource'!A#:C#,"select A, sum(C) where A is not null and B is not null group by A pivot B")
```